# Vectors Year 11

Tags: vectors

[image: Vector Question]

This is a vectors question I got, could any confirm my answer? I got $6.066\underline i - 279.28\underline j$.

$AB = \underline B  - \underline A $

(Working on Vector $\underline B$) 
\begin{align}x &= |B|\cos \theta \\
x &= 150\cos 315 \\
x &= 75\sqrt 2 \end{align}

\begin{align}y &= |B|\sin \theta \\
y &= 150\sin 315 \\
y &= -75\sqrt 2 \end{align}

(Working on Vector $\underline A$)

\begin{align}x = |A|\cos \theta \\
x = 200\cos 60 \\
x = 100 \end{align}

\begin{align}y &= |A|\sin \theta \\
y &= 200\sin 60 \\
y &= -173.21 \text{(2 decimals)} \end{align}

$\underline B  - \underline A  = 75\sqrt 2\underline i - 75\sqrt 2\underline j + -(100\underline i + 173.21\underline j)$

$\underline B  - \underline A  = 6.066\underline i - 279.28\underline j$

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! How did you get that answer? Showing your working can make it easier to verify where/if you have gone wrong

Comment: Thanks for the tip @lioness99a I'll edit my original post.

Comment: $(100+75\sqrt2)i+(100\sqrt3-75\sqrt2)j$

Comment: Updated with my working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top vector has angle $\frac \pi 3$ above the horizontal, and so its components are
$$\vec A = 200\cos\frac\pi 3\hat{i}+200\sin \frac \pi 3 \hat j$$
Similarly, the angle for the other vector is $-\frac \pi 4$, so it is
$$\vec B = 150\cos\frac{-\pi} 4\hat{i}+150\sin \frac {-\pi} 4 \hat j$$
The resulting vector is
$$\vec A+\vec B = \left(200\cos \frac\pi 3 +150\cos\frac \pi 4\right)\hat i+\left(200\sin\frac\pi 3-150\sin\frac\pi 4\right)$$
$$\approx 206\hat i-67.1\hat j$$

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can't just add both vectors as their tails are together.

Comment: Sorry, just relooked and yes I would have to add rather than minus.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \vec{200} =(200\cos(60))i + (200\sin(60))j=100i+100\sqrt3j$$

$$ \vec{150} = (150\cos(45))i-(150\sin(45))j=75\sqrt{2}i-75\sqrt{2}j$$

$$ R= \vec{200} + \vec{150} =?$$